# Polymer Firebase Binding for Location

Tags: firebase, polymer-2.x, paper-elements, polymerfire

I've been trying to bind a location value to a "note" (as in the na-notes example in codelabs) via firebase. I'm using the paper-input-place, but have tried with several other elements to no avail. So far, this is what I have (corresponding to the na-note.html document):

```
<paper-input-place is="iron-input" bind-value="{{address}}" value="{{address}}" label="Address" api-key="key">
```

And then I have this on my na-editor.html:

```
<na-note id="note" title="{{note.title}}" location="{{note.place_id}}" price="{{note.price}}" rooms="{{note.rooms}}" beds="{{note.beds}}" baths="{{note.baths}}" editable></na-note>
```

I am thinking that it probably is a silly mistake, but I've been going at it for two days and I'm starting to loose my patience, so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at above `na-note` element, `note` is an object retrieved from firebase. so, to this path, you will need to save location data of the note. So, when you received the proper data from `paper-input-place` element, you will need to save it to the note's path as a location. So, first retrive the address:

```
<paper-input-place  hide-error place="{{place}}" api-key="[[apiKey]]"  on-place-changed="searchPlaceChanged" > </paper-input-place>
```

...

```
searchPlaceChanged(p){
   console.log(p.detail.value); // You will need to see the place data, which you may like to save only some detail like: p.detail.value.formatted_address; 
   this.set('note.place', p.detail.value.formatted_address);
}
```

Asuming just abobe `note` object (at set operation) is `firebase-document`'s two way binding retrived data that you just editing.